# Check if string starts with other string in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'd like to know whether my string starts with another string. For example:

```
startsWith "(" "(test string)" == True
```

Is there such a function that comes with Haskell?

Comment: Close voters: This question isn't asking for any off-site resources.

Comment: @4castle Ask yourself the question this way: there is a huge set of standard libraries, with probably hundreds of thousands of functions in them in toto. Is it useful for StackOverflow to have one question per function on Hackage? I know my answer: a firm and resounding "no". Not only is it wasted, redundant work, it is *less searchable* than Hackage itself, because SO does not have a Hoogle-alike.

Comment: @DanielWagner I agree, there shouldn't be a question for every function. That doesn't mean it's off-topic. That would be a downvote reason. However, this function is pretty standard, and I remember searching for this function before, not thinking to use the word "prefix", so I'm not downvoting.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since strings are lists of characters, we can import `Data.List` and use the general function [`isPrefixOf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:isPrefixOf):

```
isPrefixOf :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
```

Example:

```
Prelude Data.List> isPrefixOf "abc" "abcxyz"
True
```

Answer (score 5):

## with [`Data.Text`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/Data-Text.html#v:isPrefixOf)

You can use [`isPrefixOf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/Data-Text.html#v:isPrefixOf) to check whether one string starts with another:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import qualified Data.Text as T

T.isPrefixOf "(" "(test string)"
```

To include `Data.Text` in your project, add `text` as a dependency in your Cabal file:

```
build-depends:
    base >=4.7 && <5
  , text
```

Comment: Self-answering an off-topic question doesn't make it on-topic.

Comment: For `String`s, you can make use of [`isPrefix :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:isPrefixOf). This is of course less efficient for large strings.

Comment: @chepner: It's about a specific programming problem, that's why I regarded the question as on-topic.

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: A specific problem would involve your attempt to *write* `startsWith`, not simply ask if such a function already exists.

Comment: @chepner This question isn't looking for off-site resources, and including an attempt to solve the problem in the question isn't necessary here because it was self-answered, therefore there's no risk of feeding a help vampire.

Comment: @4castle Where on Stack Overflow is Haskell's `text` library hosted?

Comment: @chepner Answers are aloud to recommend offsite resources, but questions can't ask for them.

Comment: This is not a good answer, as it unnecessarily restricts the type from `String` to `Text`, without any mention of how to convert between the two`, the advantages or disadvantages of the two, or a `String`-specific solution. The question says 'string,' so answer about strings!

Comment: @AJFarmar: In a program where you're already dealing with `Text`, this is quite useful. And thanks to `OverloadedStrings` it's not that much a leap from `String` to `Text`. But thankfully, people can add an alternative answer, like [chi did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56187890/check-if-string-starts-with-other-string-in-haskell/56187891#56189586).